# Angular 2+ - Creating a vertically expandable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am trying to create a expandable div where the users are able to vertically expand the div to show / hide information.

The problem I am facing is that, when the user drags the handler to the top, the content inside the #textarea is still showing. How would I be able to hide the content in the #testarea based on when the user is increasing or decreasing the height ?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-text-resizable-vvwbvh?file=app%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to show some code here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the display style of each child(heading) under top-panel div to **none**

1. In your **resizer function**

   - First get parent div

     - `let parentDiv = document.getElementById('top-panel');`
   - Then get all the child headings

     - `let headingElements = parentDiv.getElementsByTagName('h1');`
   - Now, loop through each elements and set display to none

```js
// Now loop though heading text and set style to none
    for (let i = 0; i < headingElements.length; i++) {
      let heading = headingElements[i]; // get specific heading
      heading.style.display = 'none'; // set display none
    }
```

[Stackblitz Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-text-resizable-styt3s?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)